# Roman and Arabic page number

Tags: numbering, page-numbering, page

In an article, I try to continue the Roman page numbering in the backmatter (for example Appendix) without starting from one again.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\def\frontmatter{%
    \pagenumbering{roman}
    \setcounter{page}{1}
    \renewcommand{\thesection}{\Roman{section}}
}%

\def\mainmatter{%
    \pagenumbering{arabic}
    \setcounter{page}{1}
    \setcounter{section}{0}
    \renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}}
}%

\def\backmatter{%
    \setcounter{section}{0}
    \renewcommand{\thesection}{\Alph{section}}
}%

\begin{document}

\frontmatter
\section*{Abstract}
\clearpage

\mainmatter
\section{Main Body}
\clearpage

\backmatter
\section*{Appendix}

\end{document}
```

Thanks a lot:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following dirty hack and small modification of your MWE seems to fullfill your demands.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcounter{frontMatterEndPage}%new
\def\frontmatter{%
    \pagenumbering{roman}
    \setcounter{page}{1}
    \renewcommand{\thesection}{\Roman{section}}
}%

\def\mainmatter{%
    \setcounter{frontMatterEndPage}{\value{page}}%new
    \pagenumbering{arabic}
    \setcounter{page}{1}
    \setcounter{section}{0}
    \renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}}
}%

\def\backmatter{%
    \setcounter{section}{0}
    \renewcommand{\thesection}{\Alph{section}}
    \pagenumbering{roman}%new
    \setcounter{page}{\value{frontMatterEndPage}}%new
}%

\begin{document}

\frontmatter
\section*{Abstract}
\newpage{}\section{Test}
\clearpage

\mainmatter
\section{Main Body}
\newpage{}\section{Test}
\clearpage

\backmatter
\section*{Appendix}
\newpage{}\section{Test}


\end{document}
```

Please check your final results for correct page numbers.
I have never seen this style and I do not know why this might be a good idea but if you need it, then do it.

Comment: Great thanks a lot! Would you use book as document class instead of an article for a Master thesis?

Comment: @fjurt You are very welcome. I would most likely use memoir for a master's thesis when following typographic traditions of Anglo-America, Australasia, or Great Britain if I could choose a class freely. See https://ctan.org/pkg/memoir and https://ctan.org/pkg/memdesign.

Answer (score 1):

Not an answer.  The default definitions from book.cls are fairly innocuous, but do contain some features you missed.

```
\newcommand\frontmatter{%
    \cleardoublepage
  \@mainmatterfalse
  \pagenumbering{roman}}
\newcommand\mainmatter{%
    \cleardoublepage
  \@mainmattertrue
  \pagenumbering{arabic}}
\newcommand\backmatter{%
  \if@openright
    \cleardoublepage
  \else
    \clearpage
  \fi
  \@mainmatterfalse}
```

The key issue is that `\pagenumbering` resets the counter to 1, while `\renewcommand{\thepage}{\roman{page}}` does not.

Comment: Thank you very much